# Bitbucket Conflict issue while deploying a branch

Tags: git, deployment, bitbucket, git-merge-conflict

I had recently merged two branches, bugFix(branch 1 ) with cssFix(branch 2) and it was successful .
Basically what I did was I checked out into cssFix branch and merged bugFix branch. In VSCode source control everything looks fine and there is no conflicts present. But now when I try to deploy cssFix in bitbucket it is saying as conflicts present along with the line number where the conflict is present, but the conflicts are not showing up in VSCode , I even checked the file to see if there is any conflict but it does not have any conflicts present inside the file, but the error only shows up in Bitbucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout to cssFix(branch 2) in local, merge the branch you are trying to deploy, you will get conflicts,
clear all issues and push the cssFix(branch 2),then try deploying it in bitbucket.
This should work.